# How can I find out with which software a website is using?

Tags: website, web, survey

I would like to know what software was used to make www.tellasda.com - I would like to make something similar with as little codeing required as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "what software was used to make..." - this could mean one of two things: 1) Whether an IDE was used such as DreamWeaver, Notepad++ etc; OR 2) Whether the website uses a Content Management System (CMS) platform such as WordPress, Magento, SharePoint... On a side note: Many developers try hard to HIDE whether a CMS was used because it opens the site up to potential threats related to a particular CMS in use. I.e. If I knew your site was WordPress [by looking at the source code] then I could try to hack your site and concentrate on only using WordPress hacks...

Comment: I would like to know what CMS is being used if any at all

Comment: OK, from looking at the source code of the page it either doesn't use a CMS, has obfuscated one it does use, or uses a custom CMS written specifically for TellAsda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site doesn't appear to use a CMS - it is a custom build.

This is evidenced by the following:

- No mention of a CMS/Copywrite in any of the header info
- Div IDs such as "frmDateOfVisit" imply custom coded forms - not generic names
- Javascript files on the site reference absolute paths (implying custom coding)
- Custom CSS Class names
- Unused CSS Class count across the site is quite low - implying no generic classes

The site (if it helps) is primarily HTML/CSS with javascript and JQuery for the forms.  It is powered by asp.net

Lookint at the POST data for the site in firebog would imply PHP is used for the site, but its kinda difficult to verify this from my current PC.

What aspect of the site is it that you are looking to replicate?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am trying to create a survey and thought they may have used some software to achive this. In case anyone else is intrested I have found 'surveygizmo' they will allow you to create surveys - though I am not sure how good they are.

Comment: Or Survey Monkey... there are quite a few good ones out there.  Alternatively, its not overly difficult to build a quick-n-dirty survey form using php POST and jquery.